# How to get Microsoft Teams usage-report via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-teams

I want to get the same Microsoft Teams user activity report which I can export from the Teams admin center via a PowerShell script.
[Teams user activity report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd2rI.png)

In the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-powershell-overview) I cannot find what I actually need. Is there a way to get Call and Chat report information from Office 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the teams user activity by graph calling method. Please find below 2 links.

Below Graph Api provides - user activity report.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/microsoft-teams-user-activity-reports?view=graph-rest-1.0

Below Graph Api provides - Report Refresh Date, Report Date, Team Chat Messages, Private Chat Messages, Calls, Meetings, Report Period
Below Api will provide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivitycounts?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Thank it helps. Btw i found on this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0#feedback) by the questions section that the other pepole have the same kind of problem as i have. --> (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7726)